# ssh-agent asks for passphrase on reboot even with AddKeysToAgent and UseKeychain enabled

Tags: macos, password, keychain, ssh

I have the following configuration in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I have a single SSH private key and I've even tried adding it manually with `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` but when I restart my computer, it still asks me once for a passphrase.

This happens on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1.